# can Apache cordova app nost non azure website

Tags: cordova

I have a mvc website for which I need to create mobile app. I am looking into using Cordova for hosting web  on mobile platform. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/run-web-app-in-cordova?view=toolsforcordova-2017

All the examples I found are for azure websites. Can non azure website be also hosted on mobile or would I have to create new front end for Mobile.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can. Just look at the official quick start guide. https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted

After you create a project described there, you'd have a www folder there, that has the index.html file. Replace it with your files, remember to load the cordova.js and plugins.js from inside of your entry file. This should be a good start.

The WWW folder information can be found here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/8.x/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#www